# Is it possible to create a query involving rows from two tables like this?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create a query where it selects row from a table based on few conditions which I can accomplish quite fine. However, I would like to figure out how to only show rows from table if the id of that record has not appeared in another table in the past 24 hours. How would I go about doing something like this imagine. Imagine the table was like:

```
ID .          | EMAIL .         | . PASS
------------- | --------------- | ---------------
1 .             abc@abc.com .     rgjoegeijerioge
2 .             ab46c@abc.com .   dgnkjrkjhrnjkrt
3 .             ab46c@abc.com .   etjhrnkrjkjhjhr

------------- | --------------- | --------------- | ---------------
transferID .    ACCOUNT .         ACCOUNTTO .       ITEM
------------- | --------------- | --------------- | ---------------
1 .             abc@abc.com .     rjek@xs.com .     book1
2 .             ab4gtrc@abc.com . xbjk@abc.com      book2
3 .             ab46gggc@abc.com  bca@lo.com        book2
```

so therefore I would want to get all rows from the first table where the email/user (or even userID if I change the table structure) hasn't been part of a row thats been added to second table in the last 24 hours.

Comment: hint: join.....

Comment: Your second table misses a timestamp when the record was added to make this even possible. And it is not clear how the records are related -- is it `email` and `account` that should match? Or `accountto`?

Comment: oh yeah, in my real table I know I'll need a date column I forgot to add in this question sorry. Yes, email and account should match. Thanks

Comment: @KmanOfficial11 you have received some good answers. You might want to put a closure to your question by marking an answer as accepted to other users know that your question had an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM table1 t1 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 0 
                       FROM table2 t2
                      WHERE t2.account = t1.email 
                        AND t2.insertion_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
                      )
```

assuming you have a column called `insertion_date` in `table2`

Answer (score 1):

Alternate method is JOIN like Himanshu mentioned:

**Table**

```
drop table if exists userinfo;
create table userinfo (
    id int,
    email varchar(200),
    pass varchar(200)
);
insert into userinfo values
(1, 'abc@abc.com', ''),
(2, '123@abc.com', ''),
(3, 'xyz@abc.com', '');

drop table if exists transfers;
create table transfers (
    transferid int,
    account varchar(200),
    accountto varchar(200),
    item varchar(200),
    created_date datetime
);

insert into transfers values
(1, 'abc@abc.com', 't@abc.com', 'Book1', date_sub(now(), interval 1 hour)),
(2, '123@abc.com', 't@abc.com', 'Book2', date_sub(now(), interval 40 hour)),
(3, 'xyz@abc.com', 't@abc.com', 'Book3', date_sub(now(), interval 20 hour));
```

**Query**

```
select u.id, u.email
from userinfo u
left join transfers t
    on u.email = t.account
    and t.created_date >= date_sub(now(), interval 24 hour)
where t.transferid is not null;
```

**Result**

```
id email
1  abc@abc.com
2  xyz@abc.com
```

Example:  https://rextester.com/UYM78253

Comment: Since [rextester got hacked last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375602/rextester-has-officially-been-hacked-where-do-we-go-from-here?r=SearchResults&s=1|54.1497) it's been preferred to use other sites (e.g. https://www.db-fiddle.com, https://dbfiddle.uk) to host demos. But this is my preferred way to implement this as it avoids the overhead of a subquery for every row in the result.

Comment: Thanks @Nick. I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN`, assuming first table is `table_1` and second one is `table_2`,

```
--We only want to check the `id` against `transferid` (simplest situation):
SELECT
    table_1.*
FROM
    table_1 
    LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.ID = table_2.TransferID
WHERE
    table_2.TransferID IS NULL
```

Second situation,

```
--We want to check `email` against `account` and `accountto`:

SELECT
    table_1.*
FROM
    table_1 
    LEFT JOIN table_2 
        ON table_1.Email = table_2.Account OR table_1.Email = table_2.AccountTo
WHERE
    table_2.TransferID IS NULL
```

Here is the db fiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5acd6dadbe6cb95f5399026f8ea3e052

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a timestamp in the second table

```
    select * from table1
    where id not in (
                     Select id from table2 
                     where date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
                     )
```